# How do I return the blogs in my database and render them by sorting them according to the most recent?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have some blog posts in my Database (MongoDB) which I want to render to the screen by sorting them according to the most recent post. Please I need a solution or tutorial link to the solution. Thanks in advance

I have tried using the .toDateString() JavaScript inbuilt method which sometimes returns the most recent and sometimes doesn't for me.

```
    <div id="top2">
        <div class="row">
            <% blogs.forEach((blog) => { %>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 thumb">
                        <img src="<%= blog.image %>" />
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3><a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>"><%= blog.title %></a></h3>
                            <p><%- blog.content.substring(0, 100) %>...</p>
                            <p id="created"><span id="author"><%= blog.author.username %></span> - <%= blog.created.toDateString() %></p>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                </div>
            <% }) %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect the returned blogs from the database to be sorted by the date created.

Comment: Could you show your mongo query ? You can achieve that at this level instead of sorting the posts in the template.

Comment: I am using this query db.foo.find({}); to return the blogs in the database. I have a toCreated: date field on each blog and want to use that to return blogs according to date created from descending order to ascending (newest to oldest).